# adding code block inside asp markup tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code :

```
 <ul class="slides">

                <%
                    int count = 0;
// tb is the DataTable i fetched  
                    if (tb != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tb.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {

                %>

                <div class="ft-item"  >

                                 <%       
                                   Image1.ImageUrl = tb.Rows[i]["timg"].ToString();
                                   Image1.ID = "img" + tb.Rows[i]["xtid"];
                                   LinkButton1.ID = tb.Rows[i]["xtid"].ToString();
                                %>

                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <span class="ft-image">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">

// I WANT TO  ADD THE CODE BLOCK : IF(tb.Rows[i]["ALERT"].TOSTRING() == "YES") RESPONE.WRITE("STH");

                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </span>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>



                <%

                                count++;

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("<h2 class='t-heading text-upper' style='color:#bd6767'> No Data </h2>");
                    }

                %>
            </ul>
```

I want to add the code block inside the asp markup tag but i cant (at the comment i left above). I did  a lot searching all asked me to do databind but  i am asking for another way and as you see , this way we cant do databind . 
i did try adding `if(tb.Rows[i]["ALERT"].TOSTRING())LinkButton1.Text = "STH"` above the tags but it will then remove my image tag

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? What benefits do you think it gives you?

Comment: i can easily work with my javascript code .

Comment: for details , inside the <ul> tag each <li> is a slider and a <li> contains 8 <div class = 'item'> so if i do the databind like you , its hard for me to put out <li> tag , this way i can handle if(i==8) . the code is cut before posting for u guys easily read .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Label` control inside the `LinkButton`:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then add the following to your existing code block.

```
<%       
   Image1.ImageUrl = tb.Rows[i]["timg"].ToString();
   Image1.ID = "img" + tb.Rows[i]["xtid"];
   LinkButton1.ID = tb.Rows[i]["xtid"].ToString();

   // set the label text
   if (row["ALERT"].ToString() == "YES")
   {
       Label1.Text = "STH";
   }
%>
```

But you should reconsider refactoring your code so that databinding does work as you will find that you will end up having more flexibility. The code that runs the page can also then be kept separate from the page/user control's markup which promotes separation of concern which will also have the other benefit of having better code readability.

This following example ASPX page that I have created should demonstrate how to achieve the same result using a databind on a ListView control.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create some test data to play with.
        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("xtid", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("timg", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("ALERT", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(1, "/some_img.jpg", "YES");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "/some_img.jpg", "NO");
        table.Rows.Add(3, "/some_img.jpg", "NO");
        table.Rows.Add(4, "/some_img.jpg", "YES");

        MyListView.DataSource = table;
        MyListView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // output the id of the button clicked.
        ButtonClicked.Text = ((Control)sender).ID;
    }

    protected void MyListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

        // Find the link button on the item's template.
        var linkButton = e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
        if (linkButton != null)
        {
            linkButton.ID = row["xtid"].ToString();

            var buttonText = linkButton.FindControl("ButtonText") as Label;
            if (buttonText != null)
            {
                if (row["ALERT"].ToString() == "YES")
                {
                    buttonText.Text = "STH";
                }
            }

            var image1 = linkButton.FindControl("Image1") as Image;
            if (image1 != null)
            {
                image1.ImageUrl = row["timg"].ToString();
                image1.ID = "img" + row["xtid"];
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
        <div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ButtonClicked" />

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="MyListView" OnItemDataBound="MyListView_ItemDataBound">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <ul class="slides">
                                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ItemPlaceHolder" />
                            </ul>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%-- The item template is used to render each of the rows of the DataTable that has been binded to the ListView control. --%>
                            <div class="ft-item">
                                <span class="ft-image">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ButtonText" />
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                    </span>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```